# Run time taking script behind Cherrypy

Tags: python, session, cherrypy

I am using `Cherrypy` to create an Application that takes user input, manipulates that data. Basically, executes a **time taking script**. And then when all that is done, it displays a new page. My problem is that by the time my script finishes execution, browser loses connection and displays 
`The page at myexample.com isn't working`or `No data received`. Although the whole script doesn't take more than a minute to execute. Any leads on how to go about would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cherrypy is a multi-threaded python web server. Due to the python [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) you cannot run a **time taking script** when answering a request because it will cause Cherrypy to be unresponsive to any new user, meanwhile your script is running.

You need to run your **time taking script** in a separated python process. The best way to do this is using a queue manager like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [RQ](http://python-rq.org/).

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644974/how-to-return-data-from-a-cherrypy-backgroundtask-running-as-fast-as-possible/36750783#36750783) to have a detailed example on how to do this with Cherrypy.