# How to exec periodically a function in CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

This code generate 3 webpages using CheryPy. It's works but now i need to execute periodically the function "PageWeb" to have last informations from a query.
How to use threading in CherryPy:

```
from Widget import showLine
from Widget import SocketLivestatus
import cherrypy
import threading


def PageWeb(cluster):
    # Open Socket
    table = SocketLivestatus(['host1','host2'], 50000, cluster)
    # Result
    Line = showLine(table) 
    HTML = '''<!doctype html>
             <html lang="en">
                <head><meta charset="utf-8">
                 <title>Widget</title>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
             </head>
            <body style="background-color: #1F1F1F">'''+Line+'''</body>
            </html>'''
    return HTML

#BEFORE
re7 = PageWeb("re7")
prod1 = PageWeb("prod1")
prod2 = PageWeb("prod2")
#MY GOAL
re7 = threading.Timer(5.0, PageWeb("re7")).start()
prod1 = threading.Timer(5.0, PageWeb("prod1")).start()
prod2 = threading.Timer(5.0, PageWeb("prod2")).start()


class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def re7(self):
        return re7

    @cherrypy.expose
    def prod1(self):
        return prod1

    @cherrypy.expose
    def prod2(self):
        return prod2



if __name__ == '__main__':
   cherrypy.config.update(
    {'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'} )
   cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(),config={
        '/':
        { 'tools.staticdir.on':True,
          'tools.staticdir.dir': "/app"
        }
       # '/fonts':
       # { 'tools.staticdir.on':True,
       #   'tools.staticdir.dir': "/app"
       # }  
    })
```

The problem is about threading.Timer(5.0, PageWeb("...")).start() return an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 811, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 1083, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I would like help to use threading function in CherryPy.

Comment: Perhaps you'd better delegate this work to external queue like RQ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36750783/595220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) only runs once:

> This class represents an action that should be run only after a certain amount of time has passed

After some experimentation, it appears that `cherrypy` does not work well with threads. The following code uses the `multiprocessing` library to create a separate `Process`. The `HTML` is shared by storing it as the first entry of a managed `list`:

```
import cherrypy
import multiprocessing
import time

def PageWeb(cluster, sleep_interval, lock, shared_result):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        HTML = '''<!doctype html>
                 <html lang="en">
                    <head><meta charset="utf-8">
                     <title>Widget</title>
                     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
                 </head>
                <body style="background-color: #1F1F1F">'''+str(counter)+'''</body>
                </html>'''
        counter += 1
        with lock:
            shared_result[0] = HTML
        time.sleep(sleep_interval)

class HelloWorld(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.re7_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.re7_result = self.manager.list()
        self.re7_result.append('')
        arg_list = ("re7", 5.0, self.re7_lock, self.re7_result)
        self.re7_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=PageWeb, args=arg_list)
        self.re7_process.daemon = True
        self.re7_process.start()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def re7(self):
        with self.re7_lock:
            return str(self.re7_result[0])

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

This code is a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should be able to integrate it with your code.

Comment: I doesn't why but i have a white page without my HTMLcode when i executed CherryPy webServer.

Comment: I added "import time"

Comment: You can debug this using `print` statements or a debugger. Try putting `print shared_result` after `shared_result = HTML` and `print re7_result` before `return re7_result`.

Comment: `print shared_result` show my HTML code in my shell. `print re7_result` show me None

Comment: Try moving the thread and shared variable initialization into the constructor as shown above.

Comment: Using a thread is a dead end. The `cherrypy` library must create a new process to serve requests. That process gets a copy of the shared variable. If you need to share data, you will need to run your periodic code in a separate process and use the `multiprocessing` library facilities to share the results.